# How to model recurency and hasMany relationship in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In my app there are `users`. Each user may have many friends (other users). If user A has a friend B then user B has a friend A - always. I will have to query collection of users to get all friends of user A for example. And I will have to also use geospacial index for this query to get all friends of user A in a given radius from user A.

I have some problem when trying to "model" this structure in MongoDB.
For now I have this (in Mongoose):

```
{
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    phone_number: { type: String, unique: true },
    location: { type: [Number], index: '2dsphere' },
    friends: [{ phone_number: String }]
}
```

So each user contain array of other users phone numbers (phone number identifies each user). But I don't think it's a good idea as one user may have zero or many friends - so friends array will be mutable and may grow significantly.

What will be best option of modeling this structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two approaches:

## Join Collection

Similar to the relation approach where there is a collection that has documents representing friendships (essentially two object ids and possible meta-data about the relationship).

## Arrays on each user

Create an array and push the object id's of the friends onto the array.

When a friendship is created you would need to modify both friends (push each friend onto the other's friend array). It would be the same for friendship dissolution.

## Which one?

The join collection approach is slower as it requires multiple queries to get the friendship data as opposed to having it persisted with the user themselves (taking advantage of data locality). However, if the number of relationships grows in an unbounded fashion, the array approach is not feasible. MongoDB documents have a 16mb limit and there is a practical upper bound of 1000 or so items after which working with arrays becomes slow and unwieldy.

Comment: Hmm so if I will assume that each user may have up to 1000 friends then I it's better to use Arrays on each user right?

Comment: But the arrays format has an error that you can't store extra info about the friendship. Which might be a problem.

Comment: Not really, you could always store objects (embedded documents) in the array that contain the friendship metadata.